# How can I insert (or copy) an image from one table to another table

Tags: php, mysqli, web-deployment

I want to copy the user image from users table

```
$query = "SELECT * from users WHERE username ='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$user_image = $row['image'];
```

and insert the user image to testimonials table as ($testimonial_image )

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO testimonials (testimonial_author, testimonial_content, testimonial_image) ";
$insert_query .="VALUES ('$testimonial_author','$testimonial_content','$testimonial_image')";
```

How can I do that please??

Comment: `$user_image = $row['image'];  $testimonial_image=$user_image` ?

Comment: I want to copy the image from the user folder to testimonial folder because  its not the same folder @grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `$user_image = $row['image'];`  try `echo $user_image` to see if you have got the data you expected.

If you have got the data you expected, try adding `$testimonial_image=$user_image` to your php code before

`$insert_query = "INSERT INTO testimonials` ...

This will make the value of the variable `$testimonial_image` the same as the value of `$user_image` that you have already retrieved.

If this does not work, there may be sql errors in one or both of the queries.

**EDIT: FOLLOWING COMMENTS BELOW ABOUT DUPLICATING A FILE TO A NEW FOLDER:**

To copy a flie, this has nothing to do with the sql:

```
copy("/images/user_image/".$user_image , "/images/testimonial_image/".$user_image)
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: your solution only copy the value of `$user_image` to `$testimonial_image`
but what I want beside that is to copy the **image file** from users images folder to testimonial images folder ! @grateful